# No sound after login in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa, login-screen

I have clean install of Ubuntu 14.04. I had some kind of freeze yesterday and after I rebooted the laptop I have no sound in system. But I do have sound on login screen - I hear the "banging" sound.

I tried reinstalling ALSA. It didn't help.

I also tried `sudo alsa force-reload`. This is the output:

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event 
snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-
realtek snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc 
snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-
realtek snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc 
snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event 
snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-
realtek snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc 
snd-timer.
➜  ~
```

I also noticed errors in [`.xsession-errors`](http://pastebin.com/wC44NfUf).

I couldn't find what else should I do.

Comment: Did you try any of this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: Trying these procedures now.

Comment: @JoKeR oh, second step helped indeed! Thanks. Adding it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

From [Ubuntu Sound Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure):

**1B.** Should the approach above fail to correct the problem (it is only known to work on some variations), you can try this next. If you are using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (Precise Pangolin) or later:

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ~/.config/pulse
```

wait 10 seconds, then reboot (putting the machine to sleep is not enough -- fully power it off and then back on). Make sure to save your work first.

It fixed the problem for me.